# Error while installing nis (3.17-33) on debian 8

Tags: dpkg, nis

I am encountering the following error

```
root@periferralvm1:~# apt-get install portmap nis
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'rpcbind' instead of 'portmap'
rpcbind is already the newest version.
Suggested packages:
  nscd
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 nis
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 98 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/165 kB of archives.
After this operation, 556 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package nis.
(Reading database ... 141416 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../archives/nis_3.17-33_i386.deb ...
Unpacking nis (3.17-33) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Setting up nis (3.17-33) ...
dpkg: error processing package nis (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nis
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

root@periferralvm1:~# uname -a
Linux periferralvm1 3.16.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt9-2 (2015-04-13) i686 GNU/Linux

root@periferralvm1:~# /var/lib/dpkg/info/nis.postinst configure
root@periferralvm1:~#

root@periferralvm1:~# /var/lib/dpkg/info/nis.postinst
root@periferralvm1:~#
```

Nothing seems to work. Please suggest possible solutions.
Tried:

- Purging and reinstalling
- reinstalling dpkg
- rebooted server
- touch /etc/init.d/nis and reinstall nis

Comment: Add the output of `sudo /var/lib/dpkg/info/nis.postinst configure` and the content of `/var/lib/dpkg/info/nis.postinst` to your post.

Comment: @Braiam .. The output of the commands that you mentioned returned empty prompts. I have updated the post.